# How to write php code inside html which is wrapped inside single quotes in php file?

Tags: php, html

```
$body = '<div data-shordcode="[woo_mb_items]"><div class="ywot_order_details top"><br></div>    <h2>Order #2717</h2>

                <table class="email_builder_table_items" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100% !important;" border="1" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">Product</th>
                        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">Quantity</th>
                        <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:left;">Price</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                         <tr class="order_item">
                *php code*
                            <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;word-wrap:break-word;"><div style="margin-bottom: 5px"><img src="'.$thumbnail.$_SESSION['img_url'].'" alt="Product image" height="32" width="32" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-right: 10px;"></div>'. $_SESSION['product'] .'</td>
                            <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;">'. $_SESSION['quantity'] .'</td>
                            <td class="td" style="text-align:left; vertical-align:middle;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>'. $_SESSION['total'] .'</span> <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">(ex. tax)</small></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                                <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; border-top-width: 1px">Subtotal:</th>
                                <td class="td" style="text-align:left; border-top-width: 1px;"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>'. $_SESSION['subtotal'] .'</span> <small class="tax_label">(ex. tax)</small></td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; ">Shipping:</th>
                                <td class="td" style="text-align:left; ">'. $_SESSION['shipping'] .'</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; ">Payment method:</th>
                                <td class="td" style="text-align:left; ">'. $_SESSION['payment'] .'</td>
                                </tr><tr>
                                <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:left; ">Total:</th>
                                <td class="td" style="text-align:left; "><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span>'. $_SESSION['total'] .'</span></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
        </div>';
```

I want to write php loop where i specified **php code** so that the table data() there will repeat as my times as the number of results in the given array.
I have tried in **php tag** and **concatenation** as well but none of these seems to be working.
Is there any way to do it like this?...any suggestions will be appreciated..

Comment: End your `$body` string, add your php code, resume adding to your `$body` string using `$body .= '...`

Comment: Create the string outside of your `$body` variable then just concatenate it into the correct place like you do with your `$_SESSION` variables.